# Has the FAA ever granted anybody a license honoris causa?

Tags: faa-regulations, faa, faa-approval

Say, anybody who made an outstanding contribution to technology, flight methodologies, etc (for example, the Wright Brothers); has the FAA ever issued a license (private pilot, etc.) to anyone that deserved such honor?

Comment: I suspect the answer is no, but I have no evidence.

Comment: My inclination is to say no -- certainly not in "modern times", as issuing an airman/mechanic/ATC certificate to someone without the relevant training would be a Bad Thing. It's possible that in the early days (back when the FAA was still the CAA - Civil Aviation Administration) pilots who had been flying before the administration was established were "grandfathered" and given licenses - It's certainly an interesting research question.

Comment: I don't think the FAA considers licenses to be an "Honor", the same way that Universities consider a Degree to be an "Honor".  A license is strictly an *license*; an authorizing document, stating that the holder has met certain training requirements.

Comment: A license granted *honoris causa* **is** an honor, same with degrees, @abelenky

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's an interesting question, and [according to AOPA](http://www.aopa.org/News-and-Video/All-News/2012/April/18/Meet-the-artist-who-designed-your-certificate) they did award one to the guy who designed the current FAA license card:

> The FAA awarded Dahlvang his own (honorary) certificate, nicely framed
>   with a gold seal.

But it doesn't say what's printed on that certificate and I assume it isn't actually valid for flight. If you give someone a real pilot's license you give them the authority to operate an aircraft and I can't imagine the FAA handing out licenses to unqualified people.

Orville Wright did get an honorary certificate, as did other 'old-timers', but that pre-dates the FAA and again it isn't clear if they were 'real' certificates or not:

- [Orville Wright](http://corescholar.libraries.wright.edu/special_ms1_photographs/1523/)
- [Evan J. Parker](http://earlyaviators.com/eparkeva.htm)

I don't know if that really answers the question, but anyway in practical terms I think it's probably a lot easier for the FAA to come up with a suitably impressive but legally worthless certificate rather than give someone a real one and deal with the legal issues involved in breaking their own rules and possibly federal law.

Comment: I could have designed a better license. However, good answer.

Comment: A little digging on the airman registry didn't turn up a certificate for Mr. Dahlvang, but some poking around on the artist's own site turned up [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/nrX9T.jpg) -- so basically just a print run with no aviation privileges :)

Comment: I could use an FAA-approved "graphic designer" license... By the way it still looks too legit and you could easily fool many people into thinking you are actually qualified to be a pilot. Heh.

Comment: @ppp can't you get a student pilot certificate with no qualifications?